# I am new to cypress+TS. Getting error while trying to access element inside the iframe using Cypress with Typescrpt

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, cypress

Issue: While handling Iframe using Cypress with TS, getting an error as

```
TypeError
data.its is not a function
```

Below code in test class:

```
getSAveCardElement()
        .click()
        .then(() => {
          getIFrame().xpath("//*[@name='cardnumber']").type(info.stripeCardNum);
        });
```

Function for Iframe Handling:

```
export const getIframeBody = () => {
  return cy.xpath("//div[@id='cardElementpaymentModal']//iframe[contains(@name,'privateStripeFrame')]").each((data) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    data.its('0.contentDocument').its('body').should('not.be.undefined').then(cy.wrap);
  });
};
```

The reason to try with each loop is that getting jquery element with contentDocument only through with each loop.

PFB error's screenshot[image][image]

Comment: Check what is returned by your .xpath() command to what you missed.

Comment: I tried again, and while using each loop, getting a jquery element. Update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function for Iframe handling that works

```
  export const getIframeBody = () => {
  let $body: JQuery<HTMLElement | Document | Text | Comment>;
  getStripeCardIframe().each((data) => {
    $body = data.contents().find('body');
  });
  return cy.then(() => {
    cy.wrap($body);
  });
};
```